# Debian stuck in login loop and constantly crashing when trying to start lightdm after upgrade

Tags: debian, awesome, lightdm, dist-upgrade

My problem seems to be quite specific. I couldn't find a case that seemed similar enough so if You guys find one I'd be glad if you could point me to it or give me instructions on what things I could check in order to get this fixed.

I am running a pretty old Lenovo x200t. I am getting the debian testing packages. I am using lightdm as login manager and awesome wm as desktop environment. That is pretty much my setup.

I didn't use that system for quite a while so when I  did the update it was pretty much all packages being upgraded.

After that my system would boot and try to bring up lightdm but fail and retry while always jumping into this screen that shows all the system checks etc. (sorry for the lack of a proper term here)

Things I checked so far:

- Disk space
- Xorg log
- dmesg output
- s.m.a.r.t. values
- if the video drivers are installed
- fsck (also while booting from usb)

thus far nothing changed. What else could I check to find the cause of the issue?

UPDATE:
[Xorg.0.log](https://pastebin.com/S3mE01Cw)
[Xorg.0.log.old](https://pastebin.com/TgmwipAW)
[Xorg.1.log](https://pastebin.com/4LVX2VY7)
[Xorg.1.log.old](https://pastebin.com/UYGcPDY0)
[dmesg](https://pastebin.com/wqJWU8dk)

Comment: Please upload your output from `Xorg.log` and relevant `dmesg` output. It's probably a configuration issue.

Comment: ok here is what I found:
[Xorg.0.log](https://uploadfiles.io/yb762)  
[Xorg.0.log.old](https://uploadfiles.io/vhvx8)  
[Xorg.1.log](https://uploadfiles.io/588dc)  
[Xorg.1.log.old](https://uploadfiles.io/32ato)  
[dmesg](https://uploadfiles.io/kg96d)  
hopefully that says something to someone :)

Comment: Using pastebin makes more sense than strange hosting, requiring tons of JS.

Comment: Ok I updated the links to make reading the files more convenient